How to give Edit access for the records user owns?
Using Perm Set or sharing rules, how do I give Edit access for a record (say Product object or any custom object that has 'Public Read/Write' access in OWD) that they create?

In the current org, the OWD is already set for Account, Contact, etc, and I cannot change the OWD now as it impacts large users.

So is there any way I can provide Edit access for some set of users who have Create access at the object level? Appreciate if you could give an example if it is through sharing rules.

If the user is the Owner of the record and has Edit access to the objects and fields, then you shouldn't have to do anything. What issues are you having exactly?

Hi @CallumMacErlich, currently the QA team has Read-Only profile in production and can access all records for Account, Product and custom objects. In the future state, after roll-out, the QA team needs access to create new records and Edit those records for sanity check to validate roll-out changes. How can we achieve this Create/Edit access for certain objects through new Perm Set so that they edit their own records and not others owned records? Thanks in Advance.

You've essentially answered your own question there. If you assign a Permission Set that provides create and edit access to the QA team without changing the OWDs, then the team will have the correct access.

Sorry, just a correction there. What is the OWD for those objects? Public Read or Public Read/Write?
